# Can jquery code be triggered by ajax success?

Tags: ajax, javascript

I know that I can add any code inside ajax success like this

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: element.href,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        //mycode
```

And mycode would be executed after previous script is done. But is it possible that jquery script alone can somehow detect certain ajax success and be triggered only by that? 
I posted this question to this forum because drupal uses behaviours which might be helpful with that. But that is my guess only. 
Thank you for any clues.

Comment: Drupal behaviors are for executing JavaScript in a Drupal page, which is not what happens during an AJAX request. When the success callback is called depends from jQuery; I don't see any way to filter when the success callback is called. Eventually, you could return specific data to the callback, and check for those data in the callback.

Comment: If you have control in the page callback that returns ajax data, note that you can return any Ajax command.  I work with ajax a lot and never needed to it the way you are asking.

Comment: @AyeshK I do not work with ajax and probably I try to reinvent the wheel here. I imagine an ajax success on current page and on same page there is a jquery script waiting to be triggered by this. But I can imagine more scripts on one page that produce ajax success. I do not want my script to be triggered by all of them. Not sure if that makes sense what I am asking.

Comment: Yes it does make sense. What exactly are you trying to do with the ajax success event?

Comment: @AyeshK On the same page I have a list of orders. Using rules_link module I change the status of orders (the ajax response in my question is from the module). After that I am refreshing the same view to show changes. For now, I just put refreshing script inside success code. But ideally I would like my refresh script to detect this particular success and be triggered by that.

Comment: If you can change the ajax commands returned by this URL, may be you can change the output command to replace/change a specific DIV? And that div can be selected using the order ID or something unique?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes this is possible to track ajax reuests anywhere in code by jQuery alone, there are some [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) in jquery you can use methods from it like:

**.ajaxComplete()**:Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete. This is an AjaxEvent.

**.ajaxError()**: Register a handler to be called when Ajax requests complete with an error. This is an Ajax Event.

**.ajaxSend()**: Attach a function to be executed before an Ajax request is sent. This is an Ajax Event.

**.ajaxStart()**: Register a handler to be called when the first Ajax request begins. This is an Ajax Event.

**.ajaxStop()**: Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed. This is an Ajax Event.

**.ajaxSuccess()**: Attach a function to be executed whenever an Ajax request completes successfully. This is an Ajax Event.

The last one **.ajaxSuccess()** is what you need.

you can use it like this:

```
$( document ).ajaxSuccess(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url == "ajax/test.html" ) {
    $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler. The ajax response was: " +
      xhr.responseText );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, could you provide a simple example how is it possible to use it in a code? How does script know that this ajax success that should trigger another script?

Comment: see the edits and if you need even more detail go through documentation and give some try as well.

Answer (score 0):

In my case y use Jquery custom events.

for example

```
$('form').submit(
    function(){
        return $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr("action"),
            data:data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            type: "POST",
            dataType : "json",
            success: function( result ) {
                $form.trigger('submit:success');
            },
            error: function( xhr, status, errorThrown ) {
                console.log( "Error: " + errorThrown );
                console.log( "Status: " + status );
                console.dir( xhr );
                $form.trigger('submit:error');
            },
            complete: function( xhr, status ) {
                $form.trigger('submit:complete');
                console.log( "The request is complete!" );
        }
    }
);


 $('form.SpecialForm').on('submit:success', myFunction1);

 $('form.OtherSpecialForm').on('submit:success', otherFunction);

 $('form.ThirdSpecialForm').on('submit:error', thirdFunction);

 $('form.OneMoreSpecialForm').on('submit:complete', oneMoreFunction);

 $('form.theLastSpecialForm').on('submit:complete', theLastFunction);
```